# Disjoint union of finitely many atoms

Tags: measure-theory

I have some problems with proving this : If measure assume only finitely many values then $X$ is a disjoint union of finitely many atoms. Can someone help me ?

Comment: $A$ is atom if for every measure subset $B$ of $A$, measure of $B$ is equal $0$ or equal measure $A$

Comment: My solution is not complete and I just realised it. I add a comment below that solution explaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Suppose $\mu$ assumes finitely many values $0 < m_1 < \cdots < m_p.$ Consider the set $\mathscr{E}$ of all measurable sets with measure $m_1;$ each element of $\mathscr{E}$ is an atom. We define a relation on $\mathscr{E}$ by setting that two of its elements $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$ are *equivalent* if $\mathrm{X} \triangle \mathrm{Y} := (\mathrm{X} \setminus \mathrm{Y}) \cup (\mathrm{Y} \setminus \mathrm{X})$ has measure zero (equivalently, if $\mathrm{X} \cap \mathrm{Y}$ has measure $m_1$). This creates a quotient set $\bar{\mathscr{E}}.$  For each class $\dot{\mathrm{X}}$ in $\mathscr{E}$ choose a representative $\mathrm{X} \in \dot{\mathrm{X}}$ and let $\mathscr{R}$ the set of all these chosen representatives. Observe that two elements of $\mathscr{R}$ can only intersect in a set of measure zero, also $\mathscr{R}$ is finite for if it were infinite, then it would contain a sequence $(\mathrm{R}_n)$ and each one of the representatives has measure $m_1 > 0$ and so the measure of $\cup \mathrm{R}_n$ would be $\infty.$ Since $\mathscr{R}$ is finite, write it as $\mathscr{R} = (\mathrm{R}_1, \ldots,\mathrm{R}_\nu)$ and consider $\mathrm{T}_i = \mathrm{R}_i \setminus \cup_{j < i} \mathrm{R}_j,$ this creates *disjoint* $\mathrm{R}_i.$ To finish off, consider $\mathrm{T}_0$ to be the complement of $\cup \mathrm{T}_i.$

Comment: Actually, there is no reason as to why $T_0$ has to have measure zero, but we can repeat the argument for each $m_i,$ and obtain sets $\mathscr{E}_i$ and then, finite families $\mathscr{R}_i$ and then, the atoms.

Comment: Ok , but why the sets which are representative are atoms ?

Comment: So, when you construct $\mathscr{E}_i,$ you take _all elements_ that have measure $m_i$ and that contain no proper subset with positive measure. That is the definition of an atom. So, you say, consider $\mathscr{E}_i$ all the sets that are atoms with measure $m_i.$ These sets may not be disjoint as they may intersect in sets of measure zero, so you need to construct the classes (as done in the answer) and pick one representative, and then proceed "to"disjoint them" so to speak.

Comment: Ok but how do we know that $\mathscr{E}_i$ is non empty ?

Comment: Some $\mathscr{E}_i$ could be empty, but not all simultaneously; in fact, the only one we can _ensure_ is not empty is $\mathscr{E}_1$ for if it were empty, that would mean that any set of measure $m_1$ has a proper subset of positive but strictly less measure, contradicting that $m_1$ is the least positive value the measure attains. (Notice that it could be the case that all the atoms have measure $m_1$ as the roll of a die shows.)

Comment: Oh ok , now i understand. Thank you very much !